# @Media Print repeated page header overlaps another

Tags: html, css, media

I have the html page with more than 5 pages. I want to take print with fixed header on each page. The fixed header working in `position:fixed` using media print.

But the `.header` overlaps on every starting of the page.

I have tried the `position: running(header);` and `@page (margin)` still same. Anyone help me to achieve this.

[image: screen]

```css
.sampleDiv {
    height: 150px;
}
   
@page {
    @top-left {
        content: element(header);
    }
}

@media print {
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .header {
        position: running(header);
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Some header<br>
    etc etc etc etc
</div>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
<div class="sampleDiv">sample</div>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
<div class="sampleDiv">sample</div>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
<div class="sampleDiv">sample</div>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
```